# locking by target object self

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm curious about the difference below two example.

case 1) locking by readonly object

```
private readonly object key = new object();
private List<int> list = new List<int>;
private void foo()
{
    lock(key){
        list.add(1);
    }   
}
```

case2) locking by target object itself

```
private List<int> list = new List<int>;
private void foo()
{
    lock(list){
        list.add(1);
    }   
}
```

are both cases thread-safe enough? i'm wondering if garbage collector changes the address of `list` variable(like 0x382743 => 0x576382) at sometime so that it could fail thread-safe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So long as `List<T>` does not have within its code any `lock(this)` statements the two functions will behave the same.

However, because you don't always know if a object locks on itself or not without looking through it's source code it is safer to just lock on a separate object.

One thing of note, classes that inherit from `ICollection` have a [`SyncRoot`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection.syncroot(v=vs.110).aspx) property which is explicitly the object you are supposed to lock on if you want to put a lock on the collection without using a seperate object.

```
private List<int> list = new List<int>;
private void foo()
{
    lock(((ICollection)list).SyncRoot){
        list.add(1);
    }   
}
```

This [internally](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,164) is just doing the same thing as you did and created a separate `new Object()` to lock on.

Answer (score 4):

In both cases, foo() is thread-safe. But locking on separate readonly object (case 1) is preferred, because

- you don't have to bother about whether list is not null (lock would then fail)
- you don't have to bother about whether list is re-assigned (assigning new instance of `List<T>` to list could cause some troubles, e.g. loss of atomicity of locked block of code)
- you don't have to bother about whether you pass list to third-party code (e.g. as result of some function), as it is good practice to lock only on objects you have under your exclusive control (it could lead to deadlock if another piece of could would lock on this object too).
- when lock protects more objects at once (e.g. list1, list2, etc.), locking just on one of them would still work (if you would lock consistently on the same object everywhere), but would lead to less readable and harder to understand code.

Lock is guaranteed to work properly even if garbage collector moves object you are locking on.